# How would I solve this, considering I have no values whatsoever?

Tags: circles, quadrilateral

[image]

I think that SQ is straight and so have tried to use Pythagoras, which leaves me with $a + b + c = ac/b$, but I don't see any values. How could I find values?

Comment: Is this question from an Olympiad paper?

Comment: I don't know - this was given to me by my maths teacher. It may well be

Comment: If you are looking for solutions with "no values whatsoever," then you may want to contact a politician. They're good at that.

Comment: Ok, I'm in a lesson now, after it I'll try to solve it for you.

Comment: You don't need any values.  The desired answer is the ratio.

Comment: The thing you're missing is $a+b=c$ which, together with $a+b+c=ac/b$ leads to [$2:1:3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%2Bc%3Dac%2Fb%2C+a%2Bb%3Dc) @oscar6721 Indeed: $a+b$ is $RQ=ST$, but $ST$ is $c$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the shorter sides of the rectangle are equal and hence $a+b=c$. Using Pythagoras, we have $$(b+c)^2+(a+b)^2=(a+c)^2 \\ (2c-a)^2+c^2=(a+c)^2 \\ 4c^2=6ac \implies \frac ac=\frac 23$$ And also $$\frac ac+\frac bc = 1\implies \frac bc =\frac 13$$ This gives $$a:b:c=2:1:3$$